# How to Reload TabContent on Click of tab in FragmentTabHost?

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I am developing an android Application ,In which i am using FragmentTabHost, I am maintaining a container for each tab, But i am getting problem to reload Tabcontent when i reclick on tabs.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.eDeftsoft.FragmentsContainer.AboutContainerFragment;
import com.eDeftsoft.FragmentsContainer.BaseContainerFragment;
import com.eDeftsoft.FragmentsContainer.CityContainerFragment;
import com.eDeftsoft.FragmentsContainer.HomeContainerFragment;
import com.eDeftsoft.FragmentsContainer.PhotosContainerFragment;
import com.eDeftsoft.Utility.CommonDialogues;

public class HomeScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAB_1_TAG = "Home";
    private static final String TAB_2_TAG = "Photos";
    private static final String TAB_3_TAG = "City";
    private static final String TAB_4_TAG = "About";
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    TabWidget tbwidget;
    HomeContainerFragment homeFragment;
    PhotosContainerFragment photosFragment;
    CityContainerFragment cityFragment;
    AboutContainerFragment aboutFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
        initView();

        homeFragment = new HomeContainerFragment();
        photosFragment = new PhotosContainerFragment();
        cityFragment = new CityContainerFragment();
        aboutFragment = new AboutContainerFragment();
    }

    private void initView() {
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(setMyCustomIndicator(this, TAB_1_TAG, "Home"),
                HomeContainerFragment.class, null);

        mTabHost.addTab(setMyCustomIndicator(this, TAB_2_TAG, "Photos"),
                PhotosContainerFragment.class, null);

        mTabHost.addTab(setMyCustomIndicator(this, TAB_3_TAG, "City"),
                CityContainerFragment.class, null);

        mTabHost.addTab(setMyCustomIndicator(this, TAB_4_TAG, "About"),
                AboutContainerFragment.class, null);

        setTabHostColors();
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("TAB_1_TAG");
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);

        tbwidget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();

/*I had Also used This But getting error when i reclick  on sametabs*/
//      mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
//
//          @Override
//          public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              if (tabId.equals(TAB_1_TAG)) {
//                  pushFragments(TAB_1_TAG, homeFragment);
//              } else if (tabId.equals(TAB_2_TAG)) {
//                  pushFragments(TAB_1_TAG, photosFragment);
//
//              } else if (tabId.equals(TAB_3_TAG)) {
//                  pushFragments(TAB_1_TAG, cityFragment);
//              } else {
//                  pushFragments(TAB_1_TAG, aboutFragment);
//              }
//
//          }
//      });

    }

    /*
     * insert the fragment into the FrameLayout
     */
//  public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment class1) {
//
//      FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//      FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
//
//      ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, class1);
//      ft.commit();
//  }

    public TabSpec setMyCustomIndicator(Context con, String tag,
            String labeltext) {
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag);

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.tab_indicator, null, false);
        ((TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(labeltext);
        // ((ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon))
        // .setImageResource(resid);

        return spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        boolean isPopFragment = false;
        String currentTabTag = mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (currentTabTag.equals(TAB_1_TAG)) {

            for (int entry = 0; entry < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
                String ide = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName();
                Log.i("TAG" + TAB_1_TAG, "Found fragment: " + ide);
            }

            isPopFragment = ((BaseContainerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(TAB_1_TAG)).popFragment();
        }

        else if (currentTabTag.equals(TAB_2_TAG)) {

            for (int entry = 0; entry < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
                String ide = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName();
                Log.i("TAG" + TAB_2_TAG, "Found fragment: " + ide);
            }

            isPopFragment = ((BaseContainerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(TAB_2_TAG)).popFragment();
        }

        else if (currentTabTag.equals(TAB_3_TAG)) {

            for (int entry = 0; entry < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
                String ide = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName();
                Log.i("TAG" + TAB_3_TAG, "Found fragment: " + ide);
            }
            isPopFragment = ((BaseContainerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(TAB_3_TAG)).popFragment();
        }

        else if (currentTabTag.equals(TAB_4_TAG)) {

            for (int entry = 0; entry < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
                String ide = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName();
                Log.i("TAG" + TAB_4_TAG, "Found fragment: " + ide);
            }
            isPopFragment = ((BaseContainerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(TAB_4_TAG)).popFragment();
        }

        if (!isPopFragment) {

            CommonDialogues.showAlertDialog(HomeScreen.this,
                    "Application Will Exit", "Do you Want to Exit");

        }
    }

    private void setTabHostColors() {

        for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {

            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget()
                    .getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);

            if (tv == null)
                continue;
            else
                tv.setTextSize(12);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mTabHost = null;
    }

}
```

When i go in inner fragments of tab1 , like from fragmentA -> Fragment B and From FragmentB -> fragmentC (and finally i am at fragmentC)  , When i select Tab1 again i want to reload tabs and FragmentA should Apper.
Any help will be appreciated. I had gone through some of tutorials and coderepository but couldn`t found solution to my problem.
How Can i reload The content Of First tab when first tab is clicked again.

Answer (score 2):

```
I had asked a question 
When i go in inner fragments of tab1 , like from fragmentA -> Fragment B and From FragmentB -> fragmentC (and finally i am at fragmentC) , When i select Tab1 again i want to reload tabs and FragmentA should Apper.

I searched a lot and come to the conclusion , We can implement OnTabChangeListner and when any tab is clicked again we can reset it.(I was having need to reload tab when it is clicked 2nd time)

    <!--Layout for Tabs -->



  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <!-- android:background="@drawable/footer" -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabframeLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/tabframe_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:background="#FBFAFA" >

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
                        android:background="#F2F0F0" >
                    </TabWidget>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>

    </RelativeLayout>



    import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.Typeface;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
        import android.view.Gravity;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;
        import android.widget.TabHost;
        import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.abc.Fragments.FragmentA;
        import com.abc.Fragments.FragmentA1;
        import com.abc.Fragments.FragmentA2;
        import com.abc.Fragments.FragmentA3;
        import com.abc.Utility.CommonDialogues;

        public class MyHomeScreen extends FragmentActivity implements
                OnTabChangeListener {

            private TabHost tabHost;
            private String currentSelectedTab;
            private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Fragment>> hMapTabs;

            final int TEXT_ID = 100;

            final String arrTabLabel[] = { "FragmentA", "FragmentA1", "FragmentA2",
                    "FragmentA3" };

            final static int arrIcons[] = { R.drawable.homee, R.drawable.photoi,
                    R.drawable.cityi, R.drawable.abouti };

            private MyTabView arrTabs[] = new MyTabView[4];

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.my_home_screen);

                hMapTabs = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Fragment>>();
                hMapTabs.put(AppConstant.TAB_1_TAG, new ArrayList<Fragment>());
                hMapTabs.put(AppConstant.TAB_2_TAG, new ArrayList<Fragment>());
                hMapTabs.put(AppConstant.TAB_3_TAG, new ArrayList<Fragment>());
                hMapTabs.put(AppConstant.TAB_4_TAG, new ArrayList<Fragment>());

                tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
                tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
                tabHost.setup();

                TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstant.TAB_1_TAG);
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                arrTabs[0] = new MyTabView(this, 0, arrTabLabel[0]);
                spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
                    }
                });
                spec.setIndicator(arrTabs[0]);
                tabHost.addTab(spec);

                spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstant.TAB_2_TAG);
                arrTabs[1] = new MyTabView(this, 1, arrTabLabel[1]);
                spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
                    }
                });

                spec.setIndicator(arrTabs[1]);
                tabHost.addTab(spec);

                spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstant.TAB_3_TAG);
                arrTabs[2] = new MyTabView(this, 2, arrTabLabel[2]);
                spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
                    }
                });
                spec.setIndicator(arrTabs[2]);
                tabHost.addTab(spec);

                spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstant.TAB_4_TAG);
                arrTabs[3] = new MyTabView(this, 3, arrTabLabel[3]);
                spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
                    }
                });
                spec.setIndicator(arrTabs[3]);
                tabHost.addTab(spec);

                // set background for Selected Tab
                TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(
                        TEXT_ID);

                // tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2882C6"));
                View iv = (View) tabHost.getCurrentTabView();
                // iv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);

                // Listner for Tab 1//
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if (hMapTabs.size() > 0) {

                                    if (tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)
                                            .isSelected()) {
                                        if (hMapTabs.get(AppConstant.TAB_1_TAG).size() > 1) {
                                            resetFragment();

                                        }
                                    }
                                    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
                                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                /* Listner for Tab 2 */
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if (hMapTabs.size() > 0) {

                                    if (tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1)
                                            .isSelected()) {
                                        if (hMapTabs.get(AppConstant.TAB_2_TAG).size() > 1) {
                                            resetFragment();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1);
                                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                /* Listner for Tab 3 */
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2)
                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if (hMapTabs.size() > 0) {

                                    if (tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2)
                                            .isSelected()) {
                                        if (hMapTabs.get(AppConstant.TAB_3_TAG).size() > 1) {
                                            resetFragment();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(2);
                                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                /* Listner for Tab 4 */
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3)
                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if (hMapTabs.size() > 0) {

                                    if (tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3)
                                            .isSelected()) {
                                        if (hMapTabs.get(AppConstant.TAB_4_TAG).size() > 1) {
                                            resetFragment();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(3);
                                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }

            /* Method for adding fragment */

            public void addFragments(String tabName, Fragment fragment,
                    boolean animate, boolean add) {
                if (add) {
                    hMapTabs.get(tabName).add(fragment);
                }
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                if (animate) {
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_right,
                            R.animator.slide_out_left);
                }
                ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

            /* Method for remove fragment */

            public void removeFragment() {
                Fragment fragment = hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).get(
                        hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).size() - 2);
                hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).remove(
                        hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).size() - 1);
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,
                        R.animator.slide_out_right);
                ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

            // reset frgment used when clicked on same tab
            private void resetFragment() {
                Fragment fragment = hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).get(0);
                hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).clear();
                hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).add(fragment);
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,
                        R.animator.slide_out_right);
                ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
                ft.commit();

            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {

                if (hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).size() <= 1) {
                    // super.onBackPressed();

                    CommonDialogues.showAlertDialog(MyHomeScreen.this,
                            "Application Will Exit", "Do you Want to Exit");
                } else {
                    removeFragment();
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                if (hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).size() == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab)
                        .get(hMapTabs.get(currentSelectedTab).size() - 1)
                        .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabName) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                currentSelectedTab = tabName;

                // make iteration for unselected tab and make normal background
                for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                            .findViewById(TEXT_ID);

                    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BDBDBD"));
                    View iv = (View) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
                    iv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                }
                TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(
                        TEXT_ID); // for Selected Tab
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2882C6"));

                View iv = (View) tabHost.getCurrentTabView();

                if (hMapTabs.get(tabName).size() == 0) {

                    if (tabName.equals(AppConstant.TAB_1_TAG)) {
                        addFragments(tabName, new FragmentA(), false, true);
                    } else if (tabName.equals(AppConstant.TAB_2_TAG)) {
                        addFragments(tabName, new FragmentA1(), false, true);
                    } else if (tabName.equals(AppConstant.TAB_3_TAG)) {
                        addFragments(tabName, new FragmentA2(), false, true);
                    } else if (tabName.equals(AppConstant.TAB_4_TAG)) {
                        addFragments(tabName, new FragmentA3(), false, true);
                    }
                } else {
                    addFragments(
                            tabName,
                            hMapTabs.get(tabName).get(hMapTabs.get(tabName).size() - 1),
                            false, false);
                }

                switch (tabHost.getCurrentTab()) {
                case 0:

                    // we can also set background color of tabview
                    // iv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // iv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // iv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // iv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.twitter);
                    break;

                }

            }

            private class MyTabView extends LinearLayout {
                int nIdx = -1;
                TextView tv;

                public MyTabView(Context c, int drawableIdx, String label) {
                    super(c);
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(c);
                    nIdx = drawableIdx;
                    // used for forground icons//
                    iv.setImageResource(arrIcons[nIdx]);

                    tv = new TextView(c);
                    tv.setText(label);
                    tv.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                    tv.setTextSize(14.0f);
                    tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv.setId(TEXT_ID);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0.9f);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0.3f);
                    layout.setMargins(0, 3, 0, 0);
                    iv.setLayoutParams(layout);

                    layout.setMargins(0, 3, 0, 2);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(param);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#BDBDBD"));

                    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    addView(iv);
                    addView(tv);
                }
            }

        }
    <!--Layout for FragmenA -->

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TAB 1 FIRST SCREEN"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Go to Next Screen" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    code for fragment A ...it is extend By Basefragment



             import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
                import android.view.ViewGroup;
                import android.widget.Button;
                import android.widget.Toast;

                public class FirstScreen extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener {
                    private Button btnNext;


                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "I am in onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_firstscreen,
                                container, false);

                        btnNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
                        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
                        System.out.println("replace");
                        return view;
                    }



                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        fragmentTabActivity.addFragments(Const.TAB_FIRST,
                                new SecondScreen(), true, true);
                    }



                }



        Code for BaseFragment is 
        extend this class with all sub fragment which you are going to add on (While adding fragment use myhomescreenActivity(This object) and call add Function in MyHomeScreen  ):




             import android.content.Intent;
                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

                public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
                    protected MyHomeScreen myhomescreenActivity;

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                        myhomescreenActivity = (MyHomeScreen) this.getActivity();
                    }

                    public boolean onBackPressed() {
                        return false;
                    }

                    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

                    }
                }


This is the link of repository on Github for further understanding.......
https://github.com/thankimanish/TabUsingFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can try moving your code inside the onCreate method to the onResume method so that every time fragment comes to front the code inside the onResume gets executed and reloads the frament.

2.You can also try overriding the  onHiddenChanged method of the fragment and reload the fragment as soon as fragment becomes visible

Comment: Still getting same problem,I am extending fragment activity in mainactivity class and Using fragmenttabhost....once the tabcontent are added how can onResume Be called on same tab clicked again.